# Change default page in GreenDroid Paged view

Tags: android, greendroid

Is it possible to start from middle page or any user-defined page using GreenDroid Paged view? I tried changing setActivePage(pagedView.getCurrentPage()) into setActivePage(pageNo). But when I wipe either ways i.e. left or right, it starts from first page only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is to use scrollToPage() after you set the view adapter, like so:

```
pagedView.scrollToPage(2);
```